# How to remove reply_keyboard in a message using telethon?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I want to remove/hide reply keyboard from a message
I try:

```
await event.edit(buttons=[])
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: you should share more code to let people understand the context, do you want to hide keyboard consequently to the button click?

Comment: @TheKill-996 yes

Answer (score 1):

You can not edit events, because at normally they are incoming not outgoing.

for remove reply_markup/reply_keyboard you should send a message and put buttons value empty :

```
await client.send_message(event.chat_id,'Some Text',buttons=None)
```

but if you have the message id of previous message you sent you can edit that message buttons:

```
await client.edit_message(chat_id,message_id,'New Text',buttons=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

`buttons=None` didn't work for me, `buttons=Button.clear()`, however, did:

```
await event.respond("Text", buttons=Button.clear())
```